# Listening and replying in background with MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I want to implement a scenario where a process have some job, and all other processes in the system makes request to this process. Ofcourse these other processes don't know which process have the job, so they have to send messages to every other process and check if they have a job. If the process didn't have a job, they would reply with -1. When the process gets a reply from the process that has job to donate, then it will take the job from it and gets busy executing the job. But while its busy if it gets a request from any other process it will reply with -1. I haven't been able to get this working. So far I have implemented a solution with MPI_Send and MPI_Recv in following:

```
 /* Master process has all the jobs to donate */
if(rank == MasterProcess)
   while(haveJobToDonate){
       /* listen to requests with MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG */
       MPI_Recv()
        /* when request received send a job to requesting process */
       MPI_Send()
   }
   /* if no job, then finish */

}else if(rank != MasterProcess){
     /* find a job */
     findJob()

}
```

the findJob() method is as follows:

```
findJob(){
   /*set target to 0 */
   while(JobNotFound){
      MPI_Send(target)
      MPI_Recv(fromTarget)
      /* if no job returned */
      if(req == -1)
         target += (target%NumberOfProcesses)
      else
         return req

   }

}
```

But as you can guess the problem is that if a process doesn't have a job, it will not reply to a requesting process, and that process will block and wait. And also another problem is that if a process got a job, it will do its work, it will not listen to requests. If a process had sent a request, then it will block and wait. And that would make the program to block.
Is there any function in MPI that can help with this scenario?

Comment: Look at the probe function in MPI.

Comment: the functions: `msgsnd()`, `msgrcv()` `msgctl()` and `msgget()` implement  inter process communication.  The caller of msgsnd() can output several messages without having to wait for each message to be consumed.  The caller(s) to msgrcv() can discriminate between different types/priorities of messages, so will have some ability to 'pick and choose' what kinds of message that will receive, without disturbing the rest of the messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the constraints of your problem, such as explained in the question, are a bit too fuzzy for me to be completely specific in the answer. For example, since the master process is the one which distributed the work in the first place, why doesn't it keep on bookkeeping it, even after all the work has been distributed, to at least indicating which process owns what? This way, at least your free worker wanting some more work knows which other worker to steal from.

Even better, I imagine that your work is initially distributed by the master by batches (otherwise, as soon as the master is done distributing, any free workers knows that there is nothing left to do). So you can have a look at [the various `schedule` policies of OpenMP](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf#table.2.5) to see how you can change your batches to manage your overall load balancing. This issue being a very common one in OpenMP, it already had been addressed there, with a `schedule(guided)` for example. This is a sort of solution you can reimplement quite easily in your master process, which avoids any sort of worker to worker communications, and which is therefore simpler than work stealing.

Now, assuming that work stealing is really what you want/need to do, a possible solution would be to use some one-sided communications. Each worker would bookkeep a list of the tasks it owns in a memory window exposed to the world. Then, whenever a process would want to steal some work from it, it would lock this window with a `MPI_Win_lock()`, then steal **atomically** the task with a `MPI_Compare_and_swap()`, and finally release the window with a `MPI_Win_unlock()`. The way the `MPI_Compare_and_swap()` would be used would correspond to comparing the index of the task in the probed distant worker's list to the task the current process wants to steal. If both match, then this means that the task is free to be stolen, and the current process steals it and replaces it by whatever means that it has been done already, or, for example, minus its rank to indicate to any other process coming later it now owns it... The atomic aspect of the action is **very important**, since another worker could try to do the very same thing at the very same time. Without an atomic probing-and-updating operation, probing and updating operations coming from the different processes could interleave each-other, leading to a wrong solution.

At this stage, depending whether or not some work can be stolen out of the new task the current worker just acquired, it has to **atomically** update its own shared window of task list with a `MPI_Win_lock()` + `MPI_Win_{put,accumulate,fetch_and_op}()` + `MPI_Win_unlock()` set of calls. And then, it can proceed with starting to actually work on its newly acquired task(s).

For a simple example of how to use these one-sided calls atomically, you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32646142/5239503).

NB, this is only available starting with MPI 3.0.